# Auto increment a table field while updating

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, sql-update

I am updating a more than one row of a single table.
I want one of the table field to be auto incremented while updating.
Any help?

I am using Postgresql.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a trigger and handle UPDATE operations and increase any field you want there. 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html